# KSQL Create Stream with spaces in keys

Tags: ksqldb

In a create stream statement, I am having a problem with spaces in keys. For example:

```
CREATE STREAM test ( 
    Date Time VARCHAR,
) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

How should I handle spaces in key names?

I have tried:

```
'Date Time' VARCHAR,
```

and

```
[Date Time] VARCHAR,
```

But both give me extraneous input error.

---

[Update] I changed the key name above from *Full Name* (arbitrary) to *Date Time* (actual). Also added a json message from source below, but stripped most of the key-value pairs and hid most values with *xxx*.

```
{
  "beat": {
    "hostname": "xxx",
    "version": "xxx"
  },
  "Date Time": "2019-05-21T22:18:06.000Z",
  "host": {
    "name": "xxx"
  },
  "input": {
    "type": "xxx"
  },
  "fields": {
    "env": "xxx"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample source JSON message please?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I updated my post with a JSON message that is similar to source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with KSQL currently (5.2.1). I have raised https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2871 to describe and track the problem.

In the meantime, you will need to find a way to change the field name to not include spaces.